# How to create a Mongodb model without using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Can anyone help with how to build a predefined mongodb schema without using Mongoose? I am not supposed to be using mongoose in my project and create a mongodb model.

Comment: If you want to have a defined js object, i would suggest you "joi" as schema validation module. mongodb has per sè no schema. But it has a "schema validation": https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/

Comment: @Marc Thank you. I will check it out.